# Module list in redis

Tags: redis

Im running redis 3.2.9 that I built on my raspberry pi. Im trying to do a tutorial to create custom modules on redis.  I attempted to run "Module List" to see if the module was loaded but get 
(error) ERR unknown command 'MODULE'

According to the docs this should work.  Can anyone give me some insight .  should I compile redis with some sort of option to support shared libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are a v4 feature - earlier versions do not support them. Until v4 is officially released, use the latest release candidate or the unstable branch from the repository.